# Look-behind pattern matches must have a bounded maximum length near index

Tags: java

Why I'm getting this error.

Look-behind pattern matches must have a bounded maximum length near index 16:

```
encodedString.split("(?<=\\G.{524288})")
```

I'm trying to split very long string into 524288 characters each

Comment: Что тут непонятного? Он режет строку по кускам и получает исключение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the right tool for a job. There’s no need for regular expressions to split a `String` into equal sized substrings:

```
String s;// your string to split
int size;// the size of the substrings (last String may be shorter)

String[] array=new String[(s.length()+size-1)/size];
for(int ix=0, pos=0; ix<array.length; ix++, pos+=size)
  array[ix]=s.substring(pos, Math.min(s.length(), pos+size));
```

Comment: thanks, i got it working with out using regular expressions

Answer (score 2):

You need `\\` instead of `\`. Try this:

```
split("(?<=\\G.{524288})")
```